# Analyze a two digit number and print sum of its individual digits

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that can analyse a two digit number from user. I used a `Scanner` object to take the input and later an array combination. This is my code:

```
class Calculate {
    public static void calculate() {
        Scanner br = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] c = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
        int[] d = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };

        int sum;
        int a = br.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digit is:" + a);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int e = 0;
            if (a == ((c[i] * 10) + d[e])) {
                sum = ((c[i] * 10) + d[e]);
                System.out.println("First digit is:" + c[i] 
                        + " Second digit is:" + d[e] 
                        + "\n" + "Sum of digits=" + sum);
            } else if (i == 9) {
                i = 0;
                e++;
            } else if (e == 10) {
                System.out.println("INVALID NO. HAS BEEN DETECTED");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My expected output (for e.g. if user enters 56):

```
Digit is:56 
First Digit:5 Second digit:6
Sum of digits=11
```

However, the output is not coming out properly; it is taking infinite inputs.Like this:

```
56
Digit is:56
23
89 
45 
.....
```

And this way, it's stuck in a loop. How can I correct this?

Comment: try putting an else statement at the end of your if/else tree that just prints "shouldn't get here" or something like that.  Then you know your logic is not working.  It probably takes infinite inputs because of the way you call calculate. Can you should your main method? Also your loop is very messy, you reset `e` every iteration, so it will never reach 10.  You shouldn't change the value of `i` either, ideally.

Comment: Do you have to use arrays or can you just use `a/10` and `a%10`?

Comment: @ArunKumar There's no need to put the language in the title. Internally its represented by tags and for google etc it is put in automatically (to google the title looked like "java - Analyze a two digit number and print sum of its individual digits - java"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of that crazy for loop, if you want to get the first and second digit of a number, use this technique.

```
int number = 457;
int hundredsDigit = number % 1000 - number % 100;
int tensDigit= number % 100 - number % 10
int onesDigit = number % 10 - number % 1;
```

Do you see the pattern yet?

Comment: What's the purpose with `number % 1`?

Comment: @jarnbjo It helps people reading the answer see the pattern. It will, of course, always be zero. In this way, you can extend the pattern  without creating a corner case for the ones digit.

Comment: Ya, got the pattern. (Although your program gives the place value :P)

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner br = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] c = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
int[] d = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
int sum;
int a = br.nextInt();
System.out.println("Digit is:" + a);
if (a < 0 || a > 99)
    System.out.println("INVALID NO. HAS BEEN DETECTED");
else
    System.out.println("First digit is:" + a / 10 + " " + "Second digit is:" + a % 10 + "\n" + "Sum of digits=" + (a / 10 + a % 10));
```

Comment: Can you also show the output? Cause I'm still getting that output.

Comment: Here is the output, for input 56:

56
Digit is:56
First digit is:5 Second digit is:6
Sum of digits=11

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code, but with little modifications so that it works fine :p

```
class Calculate {
    public static void calculate() {
        Scanner br = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] c = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
        int[] d = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };

        int sum;
        int a = br.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digit is:" + a);

        int e = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            if (a == ((c[i] * 10) + d[e])) {
                sum = ((c[i] * 10) + d[e]);
                System.out.println("First digit is:" + c[i] 
                        + " Second digit is:" + d[e] 
                        + "\n" + "Sum of digits=" + sum);
                break;
            } else if (i == 9) {
                i = 0;
                e++;
            } else if (e == 10) {
                System.out.println("INVALID NO. HAS BEEN DETECTED");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to add explanation why it didn't work earlier. Part about initializing `e` with `0` in each loop iteration even if it could be incremented in loop seems to be crucial to understanding this infinite loop.

Comment: You are right, but it is not the only reason!
The loop must be ended when it reaches the right first and second digits, so I added (break;) statement in the first (if block). Also I have added it in the last (if block) so it will end the loop when e > 9.

Answer (score -1):

This is another way (just to show another possibilty):

```
    String number = String.valueOf(a);

    String firstNumber =  number.substring(0, 1);
    String secondNumber = number.substring(1);

    sum = Integer.parseInt(firstNumber) +  Integer.parseInt(secondNumber);
```

and remember to initialize sum not only declare it:

```
    int sum = 0;
```

also remember to close the scanner `br` when you finish working with it :

```
    br.close;
```

Comment: It is not particularly clever to use `String.substring` to do trivial math.

Comment: If he wanted another tedious possibility, it would of course be possible to print the number on a piece of paper, require the operator to cut out the single digits, scan them with OCR software and then add the digits. That a solution is theoretically feasible does not mean that you should consider using it.

Comment: Well, maybe after all you are right ... there is no sense in my answer . It was not meant to be taken as the right answer, but maybe I shouldn't have bothered writing it at all ...